# Can dual-stack sockets bind to specific IPv6 and IPv4 addresses?

Tags: sockets, ipv6, ipv4

Question is in the title. Is it possible that a dual-stack socket binds to one specific IPv6 address and another specific IPv4 address? Or do dual-stack sockets always need to bind to ::/0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To listen on specific addresses you always need to create separate sockets and listen on all of them.

PS: Binding to `::` usually gives you a dual-stack socket that listens on all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, but not always. It depends on the setting of the `IPV6_V6ONLY` socket option.

Comment: "you always need to create separate sockets" meaning separate sockets for IPv4 and IPv6, right?

Comment: @keezar One per address.